# "Error in handleRes(res) : NA" from a basic multinomial logistic regression using BRugs

Tags: r, winbugs

I get the error "Error in handleRes(res) : NA" for a multinomial regression model in R using BRugs. The code below is a similar example that is much simpler and gives the same error.

The model was compiled but it fails at the initializing step.

The dmulti() seems to have some problems since the code will work if I change the outcome into one categorical variable and use dcat().

```
library(BRugs) 
library(Hmisc)

n<-100
K<-4
dat<-t(rmultinom(n,2,rep(1/K,K)))
datlist<-list(y=dat,N=n)
bugsData(datlist, file="./test.txt")

modelString = "
model
{# likelihood
for (i in 1:N) {
  denom[i]<-1+exp(beta[1])+exp(beta[2])+exp(beta[3])
  p[i,1]<-exp(beta[1])/denom[i]
  p[i,2]<-exp(beta[2])/denom[i]
  p[i,3]<-exp(beta[3])/denom[i]
  p[i,4]<-1/denom[i]
  y[i,1:4]~dmulti(p[i,1:4],2) 

}
# priors
for(k in 1:3) {
beta[k]~dnorm(0,0.0001)
}
}
"

writeLines(modelString,con="./model.txt")


modelFile="./model.txt"
mydata="./test.txt"
modelCheck(modelFile)
modelData(mydata)
modelCompile(numChains=1)
modelGenInits()
```

> modelCheck(modelFile)

model is syntactically correct

> modelData(mydata)

data loaded

> modelCompile(numChains=1)

model compiled

> modelGenInits()

Error in handleRes(res) : NA